# Asp.Net using Entity Framwork getting error does not contain a Property with name 'ID'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This is not a duplicate question because I have read questions like this here but as I said I am using Entity Framework so there is no change that I am missing property of the class.
Now I am also getting some data from database including ID
     DataKeyNames="ProjectObjectivesID"

So I am asking here what will be possible issue for this kind of error, pasting below error that I am getting while running...

```
 DataBinding: '<>f__AnonymousType25`6[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Nullable`1[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'.
```

grid view code is here **UPDATE**:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProjectObjectivesID">
     <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>"></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sector Objective">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Response") %>'></asp:Label>
                      <asp:HiddenField ID="ProjectObjectivesID" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("ProjectObjectivesID") %>' />
              </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Objective Sope">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="txtScope" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" Text='<%# Bind("ObjectiveScope") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Objective Met">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtObjectiveMet" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" Text='<%# Bind("ObjectiveMet") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
<EditRowStyle BorderColor="#9933FF" />
<PagerStyle CssClass="pager" />
</asp:GridView>
```

linq QUERY

```
  var query = (from pc1 in DB.ProjectObjectives
                                 join obj in DB.ProjectObjectives on pc1.ProjectObjectiveID equals obj.ProjectObjective_ID
                                 where pc1.IsActive == true && obj.IsActive == true && pc1.PC1ID == id
                                 select new { pc1.ProjectObjectivesID, obj.Title, pc1.Response, pc1.IsOrignalObjective ,pc1.ObjectiveScope,pc1.ObjectiveMet});
```

This query return proper data even two null data and also return ProjectObjectivesID value...

Comment: you should also provide some line of code that resulted in this exception.

Comment: We can't help unless you provide some clarification of where the code is going wrong, what action is being executed at the time and some sample code.

Comment: True, provide us some code. Now I can only guess that you may have field, not property, or you didn't add `[Key]` attribute at `ID` property.

Comment: @Naveed thats not enought - whats the code behind this control? Look at your exception - your binding `AnonymousType`

Comment: @WestDiscGolf  I have now provide the Gridview and LINQ query now should I past the result data which LINQ is generating....